# Gallery is displaying three, sometimes even four copies of the same file - why?

Tags: sd-card, gallery

I have a non-rooted Android phone running 4.0.4 (ICS). The phone has 3GB of internal storage and I have inserted a 16GB SD card. The SD card contains a number of audio and video files.

When I opened the stock Gallery app, the directories on the SD card were displayed as expected. However, there was one small problem: multiple copies of each video were being displayed.

Wondering if something had happened to the SD card, I unmounted it and inserted it into the card reader in my computer. After mounting the card, I opened a terminal and ran:

```
find * | grep .mp4
```

But the results were exactly what I expected - there was only a single copy of each video on the card. None of the files were duplicated.

Next, I tried clearing the cache of the Gallery app (`Settings->Apps->Gallery->Clear Data`). After relaunching the app, I discovered *even more copies* of each video.

One important detail to note: only the videos on the SD card appear duplicated. None of the videos on internal storage suffer from this problem.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention: other media players like VLC only display one copy of each video. So this appears to be specific to the gallery app.

Comment: Do you have DropBox with its automatic camera upload feature enabled?

Comment: Though not identical, you might want to check [I'm seeing duplicated images and videos on Gallery](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43311/16575), as the solution could apply to your case as well.

Comment: @wbogacz: No, I don't have the DropBox app installed.

Comment: @Izzy: Turns out that after clearing the cache for the *Media Storage* app, the duplicates have disappeared. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Here you go :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not the identical situation, the solution which worked out for [I'm seeing duplicated images and videos on Gallery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43311/16575) might apply here as well:

1. Go to *Settings→Apps→Manage Apps*
2. Select the "All Apps" tab
3. Find the *Gallery* app, open its entry, tap "clear cache"
4. Do the same for the *Media Storage* app
5. Have the *Media Scanner* running again. This can be triggered by either

   - a reboot of the device (ugh!)
   - unmounting/mounting the external SDCard if any (hm...)
   - attach the device to your PC via USB, optionally copy some file to it, detach it again (ok...)
   - for repeated use, take a look at apps like e.g. [Rescan Media](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addz.mediascanner), [Scan Media](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dcd.scanmedia), or [SDrescan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan) (yeah!)
6. Check if the duplicates are gone. If not, repeat everything, but this time additionally select to "delete data"