# Folder hierarchy messed up after upgrading my phone to Jelly Bean!

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, file-system, htc

my HTC Desire X recently got an update to JB 4.1.1 but after the update, the folders are not getting diaplayed in their original hierarchy in the music player apps like PowerAmp and also the default HTC Music player.

Like lets say I have three folders A, B, C and they each contain three more subfolders A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3.....

But in the folder view of PowerAmp, all the folders are listed recursively in a single list e.g. A,A1,A2,A3,B,B1,B2,B3,C,C1.C2,C3!!! Also note that in this case the folders A, B and C are only containing files other than those three subfolders.

I initially thought this was an issue with PowerAmp but since it's happening with the default music as well, I came to a conclusion the issue lies somewhere. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked those directories with a file manager? Do they look OK there? If not, you might wish to sort it out that way, i.e. using the file manager to re-arrange those directories.

Comment: @Izzy YEs I did check them with A file manager and they look OK there. The folder structure hasn't changed on the SD card.

Comment: Which leaves at least 2 possible reasons: 1) the media database got messed up (go to *Settings->Apps* and clear cache and data for the corresponding apps, they will be refreshed on the next run of the *Media Scanner*), or 2) it got confused by the conversion of `/mnt/sdcard` to `/mnt/sdcard0` and the legacy symlink (same solution, database needs to be refreshed). Please try the refresh (after clearing cache+data, simply access the device from your computer via USB, then disconnect again will initiate the media scan), and report back if that solved your issue.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks but no luck :( Still the same. Even tried unmounting the SD card and mounting it again. Any more ideas?

Comment: Unmount/mount is another way to trigger the *Media Scanner*, right. You just need to make sure first to have all its data and caches cleared. Otherwise old content might remain. We had a similar question somewhere... Ah, here it is: [Gallery is displaying three, sometimes even four copies of the same file - why?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44199/16575) There you find detailed instructions. Please let us know if the answer over there solved your issue!